# JavaScript's Zero-fill Right Shift operator combined with an equal sign. What's the meaning?

Tags: javascript

I've got this snippet of code:

```
for (;;) {
      if ((count & 1) == 1) {
        rpt += str;
      }

      // -- WHAT IS DONE HERE??
      count >>>= 1;
      // ---------------------
      if (count == 0) {
        break;
      }
      str += str;
    }
```

The complete algorithm can be found here (Section "Polyfill"):
https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/repeat

I understand the purpose and usage of a Right Shift operator but this here is combinded with an equal sign on the left: >>>=

Can someone explain the purpose of using it that way?

Comment: shorthand for `count = count >>> 1;`

Comment: Ah, okay. Like count += 1 ...

Comment: @Jaromanda X Would you like to turn your comment into an answer so that I can accept it?